# Three Vertical Dots for Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have managed in the past to add 3 vertical dots to a slideshow I created using Position absolute and moving them into position that way. then using Javascript to cycle the active class during the animation. The problem I ran into is that the dots would shrink inside of each other on resizing down to smaller screen resolutions.

Im really just curious if there is a better way to do this (ideally just in CSS3 but not against using JavaScript as well). Right now my slideshow

Github page: https://tsukiyonocm.github.io/Portfolio-Photography-Website/

I am currently messing with trying to add the dots using a UL/LI setup, but I am not sure it will react much different then it did the other way. Anyone able to offer me any input?

I would prefer this to be done with Vanilla CSS/JS as of now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
<p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do some research on a "vertical ellipsis", which is what those three vertical dots are called in Unicode. You should be able to type a single character and use that accordingly.

Comment: Ive seen the ellipsis actually in other post, but is it possible to "fill in" each of the three individual dots for that? I had assumed it was just one solid piece and not able to be targeted in such a way (hence the question above)

Comment: I have no idea, because you're not showing any code, and I've made it a policy to not visit random sites. Show your code, what you're doing now, and explain what you want to do.

Comment: The particular code above was taking from w3 schools but it gets the idea across. There is 3 horizontal dots that animate 1 at a time as an image(removed from code) animates around the carousel. As the image rotates, a new dot is darkened in this case. 

I am looking to do that, but have the dots vertical and not horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [CSS transform: rotate();](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) may achieve the effect you desire.

By adding `transform: rotate(90deg);` to the dot container in your code, it rotates to the vertical.

Comment: This actually fixed the issues I was having. I still have to place them with absolute positioning, but now they no longer collapse into each other when the screen resizes. I didnt even think of this as a possible solution!

Comment: Pleased to hear it :)